# integrating goo.gl API with external script

Tags: php, goo.gl

I have a file vars.php passed in the header consisting of:

```
$link="http://www.mysite.com";
```

I want to append a random  a random string to mysite.com like this mysite.com/?(random string) using the code below:

```
$code = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$mywebsite = 'http://mysite.com?kjdf='.$code;
```

and then pass this into into the goo.gl api. that way i get a new goo.gl url everytime the script loads:

```
<?php
/* 

$googl = new goo_gl('$mywebsite');
echo $googl->result();
*/

class goo_gl{

 var $url, $resul;

 //goo.gl construct method
 function goo_gl($url){

  $this->url = $url;

  $curl = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://goo.gl/api/url'); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user=toolbar@google.com&url='.urlencode($this->url).'&auth_token='.$this->googlToken($url)); 
  $saida = curl_exec($curl); 
  curl_close($curl);
  if($saida){
   $json = json_decode($saida);
   $this->resul = $json->short_url;
  }
 }

 //show url shorted by goo.gl
 function result(){
  return $this->resul;
 }

 //token code
 function googlToken($b){
  $i = $this->tke($b);
  $i = $i >> 2 & 1073741823;
  $i = $i >> 4 & 67108800 | $i & 63;
  $i = $i >> 4 & 4193280 | $i & 1023;
  $i = $i >> 4 & 245760 | $i & 16383;
  $j = "7";
  $h = $this->tkf($b);
  $k = ($i >> 2 & 15) << 4 | $h & 15;
  $k |= ($i >> 6 & 15) << 12 | ($h >> 8 & 15) << 8;
  $k |= ($i >> 10 & 15) << 20 | ($h >> 16 & 15) << 16;
  $k |= ($i >> 14 & 15) << 28 | ($h >> 24 & 15) << 24;
  $j .= $this->tkd($k);
  return $j;
 }

 function tkc(){
  $l = 0;
  foreach(func_get_args() as $val){
   $val &= 4294967295;
   $val += $val > 2147483647 ? -4294967296 : ($val < -2147483647 ? 4294967296 : 0);
   $l   += $val;
   $l   += $l > 2147483647 ? -4294967296 : ($l < -2147483647 ? 4294967296 : 0);
  }
  return $l;
 }

 function tkd($l){
  $l = $l > 0 ? $l : $l + 4294967296;
  $m = "$l";  //deve ser uma string
  $o = 0;
  $n = false;
  for($p = strlen($m) - 1; $p >= 0; --$p){
   $q = $m[$p];
   if($n){
    $q *= 2;
    $o += floor($q / 10) + $q % 10;
   } else {
    $o += $q;
   }
   $n = !$n;
  }
  $m = $o % 10;
  $o = 0;
  if($m != 0){
   $o = 10 - $m;
   if(strlen($l) % 2 == 1){
    if ($o % 2 == 1){
     $o += 9;
    }
    $o /= 2;
   }
  }
  return "$o$l";
 }

 function tke($l){
  $m = 5381;
  for($o = 0; $o < strlen($l); $o++){
   $m = $this->tkc($m << 5, $m, ord($l[$o]));
  }
  return $m;
 }

 function tkf($l){
  $m = 0;
  for($o = 0; $o < strlen($l); $o++){
   $m = $this->tkc(ord($l[$o]), $m << 6, $m << 16, -$m);
  }
  return $m;
 }

}

?>
```

The result is a goo.gl shortened link that is different each time. Then lastly i want to pass this into the header (on the top of the php file).

```
<?php
$picture="http://www.mysite.com/myimage.gif"; //url to a picture - e.g. http://www.mysite.com/mypic.gif
$link="http://goo.gl/blahblahblah"; //your link.
?>
```

So goo.gl/blahblahblah would redirect to mysite.com/?(random_string)

an ambitious task, but if anyone can help that would be great

Comment: There's a tag for goo.gl... amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code almost works.

```
$g = new goo_gl($mywebsite);
$shortened =  $g->result();
```

However, this needs to be executed after the class is defined.